# Многопотоковое программирование в Паскале.

Tags: pascal

Есть ли возможность многопотокового программирования в Pascal?

Answer (score 4):

Многопоточность в DOSе... что-то новенькое.  Нет, возможности "многопотокового" программирования в паскале нет и быть не может. Однако, можно эмулировать ее, переключая задачи вручную. [Пример тут](http://pascal.sources.ru/multtask/multi1.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, что Вы понимаете под словом Паскаль. В FreePascal возможно [многопоточное программирование](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial/ru) с помощью TThread.

Comment: Вобщем то нет такого языка `Free Pascal`. Есть языки `Pascal`, `Delphi` и `Object Pascal` (то, что приведено по ссылке справедливо как раз для него). 

И есть компилятор `Free Pascal`, который умеет компилировать и то и другое.

Answer (score 1):

Нет.

Это же линейный язык.

Он не предусматривает такого, смотри Delphi.

Да и смысл на паскале писать что-то многопотоковое? Кто этим будет сейчас пользоваться?